# Vue - How to show a progress bar during data fetching operations

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a progress bar using vue js and bootstrap for my desktop app.
I have this code into the template that will render the needed markup

```html
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 vh-100" v-if="isLoading">
        <div class="row m-0">
            <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
                <div class="progress rounded-0" role="progressbar">
                    <div class="progress-bar text-uppercase" id="progressBar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Into a dedicated method I've the following code, I need to implement also some logics that are responsable to load data and update a supabase database. My idea is to hide the progress bar when all the data are loaded

```js
        updateDatabase() {
            const preloader = document.getElementById('progressBar')
            setTimeout( () => { 
                preloader.style.width = '15%'
                preloader.style.width = '30%'
                preloader.style.width = '45%'
                preloader.style.width = '60%'
                preloader.style.width = '75%'
                preloader.style.width = '90%'
                preloader.style.width = '100%'
            }, 1500)
            //other db logics
        }
```

I also have a data property named `isLoading` that is set to true when the progress bar and the database loading/update process is in progress. I've noticed that the progress bar will disappear immediately and this isn't what I was expecting. How I can correctly set a timeout and modify the progress bar to reflect the width percentage changing? If I set at the end of the set timeout the `isLoading` variable, it will be immediately set to false and as I've explained the progress bar disappear. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the example given the `setTimeout` will wait for 1500ms and then run all the code inside of it, this will result in the width being set immediately from 15 to 30 to 45 to etc... if you want to display progress you will have to use an interval which increases the width by an amount till it reaches 100% and then removing the isLoading. A way to do this is by using `setInterval` like this

```js
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  if(this.width === 100) {
    this.width = 0;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
  const newWidth = this.width + Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  this.width = this.newWidth <= 100 ? newWidth : 100;

  preloader.style.width = this.width + '%';
}, 150);
```

and then creating `interval` and `width` within your data. Of course this is a simple example of how to do it but I hope this examplifies what I mean with my answer, good luck!

P.S. I have also added a random value in the example to generate a value between 0 and 15 to make it seem more natural ;-)

P.S. P.S. within `Vue` the preferred way to select an element is by using the `$refs` so setting the ref attribute on the element with for example `ref="progress-bar"` and then selecting it in your code with `this.$refs['progress-bar'];`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will follow this example to implement correctly the progress bar. Sinche I'm loading data from supabase, I will try to implement this logic insite it's then block so I will be sure that all the data are updated ana available.

Comment: I think you want to run this code before the then hook is called since otherwise the progress bar will only start when the data has already been retrieved, but I think completing it from lets say 50% to 100% within the then block would look nice

Comment: So making it run till like 50 before the then block and then within the then block completing it from 50 to 100 would look crisp!

Comment: ok, thank you for the tip. I didn't considered this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout( () => { 
   preloader.style.width = '15%'
   preloader.style.width = '30%'
   preloader.style.width = '45%'
   preloader.style.width = '60%'
   preloader.style.width = '75%'
   preloader.style.width = '90%'
   preloader.style.width = '100%'
}, 1500)
```

Assigning multiple values to an attribute at the same time will only take effect on the last assignment.So, in fact, this only executes **preloader.style.width = '100%'**

Comment: This is related to the execution mechanism of the browser. Reference video link: https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1K4411D7Jb/?spm_id_from=333.999.0.0&vd_source=c428f591567cf3f773088ac90f2eb12c  times: 20:00